# PHP Web Page Scraping

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am able to get the coding of a website with `file_get_contents` but I want to be able to get certain values out of the html. This piece of code is always the same but the value between the html tag changes from time to time. This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="cheapest-bins">
        <h3>Cheapest Live Buy Now</h3>
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>Console</th>
                <th>Buy Now Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class=" active">
                <td class="xb1">XB1</td>
                <td>1,480,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="ps4">PS4</td>
                <td>1,590,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="x360">360</td>
                <td>---</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="ps3">PS3</td>
                <td>2,800,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

How would I go about getting the: 1,480,000 .. 1,590,000 .. --- and 2,800,000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer:
find a css selector library such as https://github.com/tj/php-selector
then you could grab all `td:last-child`  elements/innerhtml

for your specific example you could just just
`preg_match_all('#<td>(.*?)</td>#', $html, $matches);`